# Extracting stress values on a certain path by scripting in abaqus

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus, odb

In visualization module in abaqus we can define a path and plot XYData on that path.

But is there any other way to extract these data by python scripting which uses a specific coordinates of model to define the desirable path and extract stress values on this path??

Comment: create a macro in the GUI to do what you want, then study the macro code.

Comment: What's a macro ??

Comment: Do File menu, create macro, perform your action in the gui, and look at the file that is created